# How to change the text size of a calculation

Tags: matlab, mupad

I can change the size of text in Mupad by going to View-> Configure -> Default Formats...

But this doesn't change the text size of a calculation that I type in.

Where can I change the text size of a calculation?

Thanks!

Comment: Under Default Formats, it says that the settings **do not affect existing notebooks**.  Are you sure you are starting a new notebook after you changed the font size?  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9143086/MuPad.png

Comment: Yes, I closed matlab and started a new notebook.

I'm running matlab on Linux; I wonder if this functionality only works correctly in Windows? Or perhaps there is another option for changing the text of calculations somewhere else?

Comment: I am not sure... the font size change worked for me.  I'll have a look and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Thanks. I checked on a windows machine too, but the functionality seems to be the same. Only the text not in a calculation seems to get bigger. Here I took a pic, to show what I mean:

http://tinypic.com/r/10y47yc/8

Answer (score 0):

Go to: View -> Configure -> Default Formats -> Calculations.
In combo box "Format:" select "Input Characters". Change Size and press OK.
Open a new Notebook, from  File->New Notebook.  Your calculation font has changed!